# How to get Fermat's descent working on the conic $x^4+y^4=2z^2$?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, infinite-descent

Fermat solved the Diophantine equation $(x^2)^2 + (y^2)^2 = z^2$ using descent, the key step was using the Pythagorean triples:

- $x^2 = u^2 - v^2$
- $y^2 = 2 u v$
- $z = u^2 + v^2$

but then it is seen that $x,v,u$ is another Pythagorean triple,

- $x = m^2 - n^2$
- $v = 2 m n$
- $u = m^2 + n^2$

then the observation that $y^2 = 2^2 u m n$ (along with some coprimality conditions) implies that $u$,$m$ and $n$ are squares - which gives us the descent step needed.

---

I wanted to use this technique to solve $(x^2)^2 + (y^2)^2 = 2 z^2$ but it does not seem to work out. Parameterizing the curve through $(1,1,1)$ gives:

- $x^2 = -m^2 - 2 m n + n^2$
- $y^2 = m^2 - 2 m n - n^2$
- $z = m^2 + n^2$

Nothing here seems to match up so well with the original problem (as it did in Fermat's case) and parameterizing through different points doesn't help either.

---

Is there any way to make descent work here? Was Fermat just lucky or is there a reason why descent can't work out here?

---

update: I found the parametrization

- $x^2 = 2m^2 - n^2$
- $y^2 = 2m^2 - 4mn + n^2$
- $z = 2m^2 - 2mn + n^2$

which looks like a better candidate for descent but I haven't been able to actually perform it. Since I cannot see how to show that $n$ and $x$ are both squares.

Comment: @quanta: I remembered that it seems to appear in other places such as the book by A.Weil; however, I am not very sure, and maybe using some identities like the variations of the multiplicative formulae for pell's equations?

Comment: And +1 for the attempt to use the thoughts of group theory to other interesting Diophantine equations :).

Comment: Are you looking for a solution that uses descent or any solution (possibly using a somewhat similar idea)?

Comment: @milcak, in this thread I am asking how to do descent directly on this curve. In [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26591/how-would-you-solve-the-diophantine-x4y4-2z2) I am just asking for any approaches to solving it.

Comment: @quanta, I'm really not sure what you want. You've got a method for relating it to another equation and then solving that other equation by descent; can't you just "pull back" the descent on the other equation to a descent on this one?

Comment: @Gerry, I don't know. It's not clear to me why descent should be so natural on the circle but not any other conics.

Comment: Fair enough. If you don't get an answer here by the time the bounty runs out, you might consider posting it to MathOverflow.

Answer (score 4):

You can't show that $x$ is a square because $x$ needn't be a square. $x=y=17$, $z=289$ is a solution.

But Mordell, Diophantine Equations, page 18 proves that the only solution of $x^4+y^4=2z^2$ with $\gcd(x,y)=1$ is $x=\pm1$, $y=\pm1$. Sketch: $x$ and $y$ are both odd; $$z^4-x^4y^4=\left({x^4-y^4\over2}\right)^2;$$ now it follows from his Theorem 2, namely, $x^4-y^4=z^2$, $\gcd(x,y)=1$, has only $x=\pm1$, $y=\pm1$, or $x=\pm1$, $y=0$. He does Theorem 2 by descent.

Comment: Indeed, $x=y$, $z=x^2$ is a solution for any $x$.