# How would you solve the diophantine $x^4+y^4=2z^2$

Tags: diophantine-equations

I would like to know any way of solving the diophantine equation $x^4+y^4=2z^2$. Or ideas that seem worth trying out.

By solving I mean fining all solutions and proving there are no more.

Keith Conrad showed how to reduce this equation to a different one which was solved by Fermat in his notes about Fermat descent, other than I have no ideas how to solve it. I tried to do descent on it directly but that seems completely impossible so I am interested in other techniques. Thanks very much.

Comment: page 451 of *Number Theory: Analytic and modern tools* by Henri Cohen shows how to reduce it to an elliptic curve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick spot of googling found [Two fourths and a square.](http://www.mathreference.com/num-zext,442.html)

Look at pattern six: the unique coprime solution is $1^4+1^4=2 \cdot 1^2 .$

Comment: Strictly that is the unique *coprime* solution.  So the complete solution is $(x,y,z) = (n, \pm n, \pm n^2)$ for any integer $n$

Comment: @Henry: Yes, I meant coprime solution, though I should have stated it explicitly.