# There don't exist $a, b$ positive integers such that $a^2 + b^2$ and $a^2 - b^2$ are perfect squares

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

I need to prove that there don't exist $a, b$ positive integers such that $a^2 + b^2$ and $a^2 - b^2$ are perfect squares.

I suopose that $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$ and $a^2 - b^2 = d^2$ with $c, d$ positive integers, so 
$$(a^2 + b^2)(a^2 - b^2) = c^2d^2$$
Therefore
$$(a^2 + b^2)(a^2 - b^2) = (cd)^2$$
and 
$$a^4 - b^4 = (cd)^2$$
but this equation doesn't have solution in positive integers.

Is that right?

Comment: why doesnt the last one have solutions?

Comment: "*And also, can you help with this?*"  That is a completely unrelated question to the first and deserves its own separate post.  Do not edit it into this post.

Comment: The last equation doesn't have solutions in the positive integers about Fermat Theorem.

Comment: @Macavity The case when $a$ and $b$ are both odd is not so easily reduced.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen  $1+1$ Isn't a square $\mod 4$.

Comment: Is my proof  right or no?

Comment: @Macavity Ah, of course. Still, “not so easily” still stands, sort of. I was just thinking of splitting off common powers of $2$ as far as possible, not the next step.

Comment: No, the equation $a^4-b^4=x^2$ is not violating Fermat's theorem.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen I invite you to show the case n=4, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem_for_specific_exponents#n.C2.A0.3D.C2.A04

Comment: Oh, *that* Fermat theorem. Okay, then. I thought you meant Fermat's *last* theorem.

Comment: Hmmm. you have a point.  This problem is equivalent to Fermats Right Triangle theorem, but I think referring to it and not proving FRRT is avoiding the point of the excercise.  Your proof is legitimate (if you refer to FRRT) but I might call upon you to then prove FRRT.

Comment: @fleablood what is FRRT?

Comment: Fermat's Right Triangle Theorem.  That $x^4 - y^4 = z^4$ has no integer solutions.  You were the one who quoted it.

Comment: Hmmm.  Two Rs and a T don't make one R and two Ts, do they?

Comment: Thank you. Well, in my class I did the proof of FRTT. But, I am really nervous because I don't know if my proof is ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $a^4-b^4=(cd)^2$ then that yields $b^4+(cd)^2=a^4$ . @awllower proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/339410/x4y4-2z2-has-only-solution-x-y-z-1?noredirect=1&lq=1) that there can never exist a right triangle with integer sides such that a leg and the hypotenuse can be perfect squares.

Comment: You mean $b^4+(cd)^2=a^4$, but it still works