# Prove there are no positive natural solutions to the system of equations: $X^2+Y^2=Z^2$ and $Z^2+Y^2=V^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove there are no positive natural solutions to the system of equations: $X^2+Y^2=Z^2$ and $Z^2+Y^2=V^2$.

I've tried several techniques and gotten little progress. I do not know what to do.

Comment: Welcome to the stack exchange! Can you explain what you have tried so far?

Comment: Your first equation can be rewritten as $Z^2 - Y^2 = X^2$, so along with $Z^2 + Y^2 = V^2$, note that a duplicate would then be [There don't exist $a, b$ positive integers such that $a^2 + b^2$ and $a^2 - b^2$ are perfect squares](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2304560/602049). Also note this was found using [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24c%5E2%3Da%5E2-b%5E2%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Aintegers&p=1).