# Solution to the Diophantine equation $x^4+y^4=2z^2$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Does there exists a nontrivial positive integer solution with $x\ne y,$ of
$$x^4+y^4=2z^2.$$

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26591/how-would-you-solve-the-diophantine-x4y4-2z2?lq=1.

Comment: The answer referred to in the previous comment is simply a reference to a possibly evanescent web site.

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/339410/11619) may be a better duplicate. For the reason pointed out by André.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: Sorry, yes. It should have been the other web site.

Comment: The fact that $x^4\pm y^4=z^2$ has no non-trivial solutions goes back to Fermat, and is standard first number theory course material. A solution that uses this seems perfectly reasonable.

Answer (score 2):

First, I suppose that you know there no exist $x,y,z\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that
$$x^4-y^4=z^2.$$
You might have seen this while proving FLT for $n=4$ and further theorems. I can give you a hint for this if you need.

If $x^4+y^4=2z^2$, we have
$$z^4-(xy)^4=\left({x^4-y^4\over2}\right)^2.$$
Due to the above result, $z=0$ or $x=0$ or $y=0$ or $|x|=|y|$, and these are all trivial solutions.

Thus, there is no non-trivial solution.