# Question on positive integer solutions of $x^4-y^4=z^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose the equation $x^4-y^4=z^2$ has solution(s) in positive integers. Then show that the least $x$ value of these solutions is odd.

---

Here is my attempt using contradiction
let $x=2k$ $$(2k)^4-y^4 = z^2$$

Any hint/help on how one should go about finding a contradiction ? Thanks!

Comment: see [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153546/solving-x4-y4-z2).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the least positive solution $(x,y)=1$

So both of $x,y$ can not be even

If $x$ is even and $y$ is odd

$x^4\equiv0\pmod4, y^4\equiv1\pmod4\implies x^4-y^4\equiv-1\pmod4$

But $z^2\equiv0,1\pmod4\not\equiv-1$

Comment: that looks brilliant! also i think that mod 4 trick works for showing $x^2-y^2 = z^2 $ and $(x,y)=1$ implies $x$ is odd and $y$ is even. thank you so much