# Show that $x^2 + y^2$ and $x^2 - y^2$ cannot both be perfect squares at the same time where $x, y \in \mathbb{Z}^+$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

> Show that $x^2 + y^2$ and $x^2 - y^2$ cannot both be perfect squares at the same time where $x, y \in \mathbb{Z}^+$.

I think that $x^2 + 2xy + y^2$ and $x^2 + y^2$ are not consecutive squares since the difference is even. I think it has some relation with other squares like $(x+y)^2$ and $(x-y)^2$.

How should I proceed? I would love some hints.

Comment: I'm sure there was a question in MSE that $a+b $ and $a+2b$ cannot be squares at the same time.

Comment: what is perfect square?

Comment: @sixulm Squares of integers.

Comment: @N.S.JOHN I see, so it's simply square.

Comment: I believe it means _x_ and _y_ are both non-zero integers.

Comment: @McCheng Of course.

Comment: I think that this proof can be modified for Fermat's Last Theorem where $n=4$. This question itself can be a different form of asking for a proof of the FLT where $n=4$. No doubt my problem sheet says this question was asked by Fermat.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Suppose $x^2+y^2=a^2$ and $x^2-y^2=b^2$, then by multiplying them you get $x^4-y^4=(ab)^2$. This last equation has no non-trivial solution; see e.g. [Solving $x^4-y^4=z^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153546/solving-x4-y4-z2).

Comment: This proves a stronger result - that $x^2+y^2$ and $x^2-y^2$ can't have their product equal to a square (except for trivial cases).

Comment: @user236182 Exactly.

Comment: I think that this proof can be modified for Fermat's Last Theorem where $n=4$. This question itself can be a different form of asking for a proof of the FLT where $n=4$. No doubt my problem sheet says this question was asked by Fermat.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

If $ x^2+y^2=c^2$ is a [Pythagorean triple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple) then there are two integers $m,n$ such that
$$
x=m^2-n^2 \qquad y=2mn \qquad c=m^2+n^2
$$

so
$$
x^2-y^2=(m^2-n^2)^2-4m^2n^2=m^4+n^4-6 m^2n^2
$$

Comment: Provided $x$ and $y$ are coprime, but this is not an essential restriction. You should also justify why $x$ is odd and $y$ is even (after reduction to a primitive Pythagorean triple).

Comment: Why can't $m^4+n^4-6 m^2n^2$ be a perfect square?

Comment: Let m^2=x & n^2=y  Then  the equation reduces to x^2-6xy+y^2 In which the discriminant is 0 if and only if y=8 or n=2\sqrt 2  So this would not have any integer solution