# Pythagoras theorem twice

Tags: number-theory, pythagorean-triples

Is there any pair of **positive integers**,$a,b,c,d$,that $a^2+b^2=c^2$ and $b^2+c^2=d^2$ holds true?

Thanks!

Comment: @peterwhy no,it is not included.

Comment: You may check that [$x^2 + y^2$ and $x^2 - y^2$ cannot both be perfect squares at the same time where $x, y \in \mathbb{Z}^+$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1754266/89922)